# Assignment of base references aliasing non copyable derived objects

Tags: c++

I had a discussion with a colleague on the need to mark an abstract base class as non copyable. I did not see the need for this, since the base class is abstract therefore we cannot have instances of base, so copying through base references is not an issue. Derived classes can decide for themselves if copying should be allowed or not. 
However, my colleague showed me a case of assignment of base references that surprised me quite a bit.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
struct B
{
    virtual void foo() = 0;
    virtual ~B(){}
};

struct D : public B
{
    D(int i): data(i){}
    void foo() override {printf("%d", data);}
    int data;

    D& operator=(D) = delete;
    D(const D&) = delete;
};

int main()
{
    D d(1);
    D d2(2);
    d.foo();
    d2.foo();

    B& b = d;
    B& b2 = d2;
    b.foo();
    b2.foo();

    b = b2; // what is this doing?
    b.foo();
    b2.foo();

    d.foo();
    d2.foo();
}
```

The code above outputs: `12121212`. I really do not understand what is going on here. What does `b = b2;` do? I expected a compile error here.

Comment: What's happening is that `B` has an assignment operator.

Comment: Ok, but what is it assigning since there cannot be a B instance? And does this justify marking interfaces/base classes as non copyable?

Comment: It assigns to the `B` subobject of the `D`.

Comment: @molbdnilo which is probably fine if B only contains methods and no members.

Comment: I mean, the code is obviously wrong, but it is not really harmful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't define a copy-assignment operator so one gets defaulted for you.

The defaulted one is not `virtual`, so it will copy any member variables of the `B` sub-object of `d2` to the `B` sub-object of `d`.  (`B::operator=` knows nothing about `D::operator=`).

Using base class `operator=` like this does break encapsulation in the general case; although in this case since `B` has no member variables and no base classes, this line will actually have no effect.

So it might be overly defensive to mark `B` as noncopyable here; since it would force any descendant classes that you *do* want to be copyable to jump through hoops to re-enable copying.